# What is the meaning of this git graph?

Tags: git, gerrit

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
* f44f80a (ma-188) MA-188 Display device details.
| * 41f17bc (HEAD -> ma-198) MA-198 Edit device details.
| * bd7158d MA-188 Display device details.
|/
| * 595a49b (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Updated Jenkins build + 
bump version to 0.1.18
|/
* c0bc4be Bump version to 0.1.17
*   31c0ecb Merge "Relocate apps"
|\
| * ab5170b Relocate apps 
* | c8637de Remove 'no-unused-imports' from tslint
```

As there are two different commit for same message (f44f80a and bd7158d). I am not able uderstant what does this mean.

Comment: It means that there are two different commits with the same message, on two separate branches (ma-188 and ma-198).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the commit has been cherry-picked for example. This creates a new commit with the same message, that fits in the context where it was cherry-picked into.

It is also possible that someone created a completely unrelated commit and copied the commit message from somewhere. This is perhaps less likely.

If the two branches in your example are merged, it is likely that the cherry-pick case will not cause any merge confusion at all.

Comment: Martin, Thank you for your quick reply. If branch ma-188 and ma-198 are merged with master. Will it cause merge conflict?

Comment: Note that considering that both those commits have the same parent, it is very unlikely that this was (just) a cherry pick. It’s more likely that the commit was amended, maybe for the ma-198 branch. But we can really just guess that from the graph; actually *looking* at the commits would likely explain everything immediately..

Comment: @VivekS Yes, it would likely cause a merge conflict since they appear to be *different*. You should look at the commits to see what they do and how they differ and then make an educated decision on which version you want to continue using.

Comment: Why are we bothering with this, if those branches were already merged to the master? You can try doing a `git diff` between each of those branches and `origin/master` - just make sure to `git fetch`, first.